# Usages of babel.js in npm modules

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

I'm currently gathering knowledge about ES6 and how javascript community deals with new changes.

Looks like everybody use babel now to write ES6 code freely.

But right now 99% of public npm packages has support for ES5. Even pretty new ones created in 2015 or 2016. My thought was that they use ES6 and then transpile it to ES5. But looking through random popular modules I couldn't find anyone which use babel. Most people still use clean ES5 in npm packages.

What's going on? Is there something hard for them to use babel? They don't want to use ES6? Or they simply don't need it? It there a convention to not do it? Problems etc?

I was going to write an npm module using ES6 and publish transpiled code with babel to ES5. Should I do it or use clean ES5?

Comment: "*I couldn't find a single npm module which use babel*" - [Really?](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/babel-core)

Comment: @Bergi I've edited my question. What I meant was - quick-checking modules which I know - I see they don't use babel.

Comment: Because popular modules are usually "older" than ES6. That means they have code written before Babel and ES6 were "usable". No one is going to start rewriting something perfectly functional, then debug it too, just for the sake of ES6. And all of this considering that everyone is fine with transpiling everything all the time, which is not really true, so in reality the thing you are expecting to see right now is going to happen two years from now.

Comment: I'd also point out that Babel is very widely used in front-end NPM packages - [React](https://github.com/facebook/react) and [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/), for example. It's just Node-specific packages where it's not really taken off yet.